# How to sum value by month and assign two different variables?

Tags: json, laravel, chart.js

I wish to sum up payment_amount by created_at date and assign the total by month to two different variables so I can plot on charts js x and y axis.

So far i have output json string using the below code.

```
public function index()
{

    $data = [
        'period' => Payment::all('created_at', 'payment_amount')->groupBy(function($date) {
             return Carbon::parse($date->created_at)->format('F');
        })->tojson(),
    ];

    //dd($data);
    return view('admin.dashboard', $data);  
}
```

so to one json string I wish to have 
$created_at //which goes on the x axis 
$total payment_amount //which goes on y axis.

Here is the charts js part i need to set the variables...

```
var barChartData = {
    labels: <?php echo $created_at; ?>, //by month.
    datasets: [{
        label: 'Revenue',
        backgroundColor: "rgba(220,220,220,0.5)",
        data:  <?php echo $payment_amount; ?>, //summed up by month
    }]
};
```

Comment: Have you attempted creating a chart with chart.js?  What issues are you having?

Comment: The issue is printing one as a label and one as data (sum total by month)...How do I access the label and data to declare the variables in charts js.

Comment: You may want to change your group by to use the year and month - `Y-m`. Otherwise months from different years will be displayed in a single result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do it all in the query:

```
$data = Payment::selectSub('MONTH(created_at)', 'month')
    ->selectSub('SUM(payment_amount)', 'total_payments')
    ->groupBy('month')
    ->get();
```

**UPDATE**

To separate your controller would look like:

```
public function index()
{
    $data = Payment::selectSub('MONTH(created_at)', 'month')
        ->selectSub('SUM(payment_amount)', 'total_payments')
        ->groupBy('month')
        ->get();

    return view('admin.dashboard', compact('data'));  
}
```

Then in our view:

```
var barChartData = {
    labels: {{ $data->pluck('month') }}, //by month.
    datasets: [{
        label: 'Revenue',
        backgroundColor: "rgba(220,220,220,0.5)",
        data:  {{ $data->pluck('total_payments') }}, //summed up by month
    }]
};
```

Comment: I then get this when I output toJson from controller..how do imap this to X and y?

array:1 [▼
  "data" => "[{"month":2,"total_payments":"720.00"},{"month":3,"total_payments":"500.00"}]"
]

Comment: What version of Laravel are you using?

Comment: Version 5.3 is what I am using.